# Could not resolve hostname datanode1: Name or service not known

Tags: 14.04, aws, hadoop, cluster

I am building an SSH connection with my namenode and two datanodes on AWS. When I try to copy the config & my `.pem` file from namenode to datanodes, I get the following error:

```
 Could not resolve hostname datanode1: Name or service not known
```

My command is:

```
scp ~/.ssh/hadoop-cluster-key.pem ~/.ssh/config datanode1:~/ssh
```

My config file is

```
 Host namenode  
     HostName ec2-18-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-2.compute.amazonaws.com
     User ubuntu
     IdentifyFile ~/.ssh/hadoop-cluster-key.pem
    Host datanode1  
     HostName ec2-18-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-2.compute.amazonaws.com
     User ubuntu
     IdentifyFile ~/.ssh/hadoop-cluster-key.pem
    Host datanode2  
     HostName ec2-18-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX-2.compute.amazonaws.com
     User ubuntu
     IdentifyFile ~/.ssh/hadoop-cluster-key.pem
```

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: You could add `-v` to your `scp` command. That should bring up a line similiar to `....ssh/config line 5: Applying options for...` to verify the config is read and matches.

Comment: Where do you issue your `scp` command? On "namenode"? Where is your config file located (what host, what directory, what filename)?

Comment: I doubt your config file posted is read in. `IdentifyFile` is not a valid configuration and should fail with `Bad configuration`.

Comment: @Thomas You have eagle eyes ;-) Btw, I guess the config is located on _localhost_ while the command is issued on _namenode_. I mean, the OP says _"copy … file from namenode to datanodes"_

Comment: @PerlDuck: good guess. That would explain things.

Comment: Thanks PerlDuck & Thomas for the replies. I am firing this command from my namenode terminal

Comment: My config file is located in ~/.ssh folder of my namenode.

Comment: Any replies to this.

Answer (score 1):

SSH is not going to read your Hadoop configuration files for hostnames.

Put "namenode", "datanode1" and "datanode2" into your /etc hosts file on each server. Now those hostnames will resolve.

The /etc/hosts file will look like this (added content). Change the IP addresses to be your VPC ***private*** IP address for each EC2 instance.

```
10.0.0.10 namenode
10.0.0.11 datanode1
10.0.0.12 datanode2
```

Note: For production systems I would use Route 53 with private zones for DNS resolution inside the VPC.

Note: Just copying the .pem file to the `.ssh` directory on each server will not be enough to enable "passwordless SSH". You will also need to extract the public key from the key pair (.pem file) and add this to `.ssh/authorized_keys`.

The following command will extract the public key. Then "append" the contents of the public key to .ssh/authorized_keys.

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/hadoop-cluster-key.pem > ~/.ssh/hadoop-cluster-key.pub

cat ~/.ssh/hadoop-cluster-key.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You will need to repeat the second command on each node of your cluster.